# Is it possible to have an Apache .htacces file chide index.fcgi in the url

Tags: apache, flask, fastcgi

My hosting provider just announced that they are dropping support for Passenger/WSGI.  I have a flask app that has been running for a while. The basic structure was:

```
host_login_dir/
    virtualHostBase/
        passenger.py
        Public/
            all the flask app stuff...
```

Now, as far as I know that changes to:

```
host_login_dir/
    virtualHostBase/
        Public/
            index.fcgi
            all the flask app stuff...
```

My question is about the observed URLs between the Passenger version and the FastCGI version.  With Passenger, the default URL was:

```
https://my.company.com/
```

The FastCGI URL is

```
https://my.company.com/index.fcgi
```

I only have access to `.htaccess` files.  Is there a way to "hide" `index.fcgi` in the URL and otherwise have the app URLs function as They used to?

I have seen: [Hiding fcgi script file name from url in django app hosted with fastcgi and apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38492162/hiding-fcgi-script-file-name-from-url-in-django-app-hosted-with-fastcgi-and-apac) and that does hide the script if it is not specified in the URL but If I go to some other app link the script name appears, a la: start at:

```
https://my.company.com/
```

click a link that takes me to the "Past Event" view and the URL changes to:

```
https://my.company.com/index.fcgi/Past
```

**Edit** I am using the `.htaccess` directives from the link above.  They are:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
   <Files ~ (\.fcgi)>
       SetHandler fcgid-script
       Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
   </Files>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```